# Can we apply lock to window phone from app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am developing an app in window phone 8, and I need the functionality of lockscreen in it.

So my question:

Is there any way to set the lock screen through the app without pressing the power button of the phone?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to lock the screen via code in Windows Phone 7.x or 8.